# Getting my Visual Studio (Ent) generated docker container up to DigitalOcean

Tags: visual-studio, digital-ocean

While being a seasoned developer, my experience with Docker is limited. I have a Asp.net core app that when i created it supports docker. When the app starts, it creates the docker image and runs it. Magic.

I and working on a proof of concept that says that I can run the container (image) in the cloud at digitalOcean. I start to create a droplet and saved my local image to a tar but that format is not accepted. I do not know how to proceed.

Is there a way I can tell my visual studio about DigitalOcean and have it push it up there or how do I convert it to a format that DO will accept? Or is it best to push my code to github and let it do it?? I just need it to work without recreating the wheel.